# problem about continuity

Tags: real-analysis

is there anyone who can help me to solve this problem?

Let be $f,g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ both continuous and $D\subseteq \mathbb R$ a subset dense in $\mathbb R$. Supose $f(x)=g(x)$, for all $x \in D$. Show that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: What is the good property about dense subsets?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Show that $\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$ that contains $D$. You may want to consider the preimage of $\{0\}$ under the function $h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ for this particular situation.

Comment: This should work whenever the codomain is a topological group, right?

Comment: @dfeuer: It actually works whenever the codomain is a Hausdorff space, and the domain is some topological space. Not sure if topological group is related.

Comment: Oh, I see now. If $f(x) \ne g(x)$, then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are separated by neighborhoods $N \ni f(x)$ and $M \ni g(x)$. Then $f^{-1}[N] \cap g^{-1}[M]$ will be a neighborhood of $x$ in which no point has equal images under $f$ and $g$. I was stupidly thinking about subtraction in a ($T_1$, hence Hausdorff) topological group. But your way is obviously better.

Comment: @dfeuer: Not at all, just more general. Honestly, the easiest way in this situation is to approach it exactly as you suggest--through subtraction--though we can still prove the result even when we haven't got the luxury of a subtraction operation, and functions from a space to itself.

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ then you can get every number $x\in\mathbb{R}$ as a limit of some sequence $(x_{n})$ whose elements lie in $D$. Therefore, you have $$f(x)=f(\lim_{n}x_{n})=\lim_{n}f(x_{n})=\lim_{n}g(x_{n})=g(\lim_{n}x_{n})=g(x).$$